# Usage of Django validators in nullable field

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

I have a model with a field:

```
last_watched_episode = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    null=True,
)
```

And in this field I want to store either Null or positive integers gte 1 to  max one that  PositiveSmallIntegerField is able to hold (from 1 to 32767 ).

I want to enforce validation on a model level ,so that I included full_clean() to save():

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
    self.full_clean()
    super(SeasonModel, self).save(
        force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None
    )
```

Problem is when I apply  a MinValueValidator or custom validator to this field I get following error message:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'last_watched_episode': ['This field cannot be blank.']}
```

each and every time when saved value is omitted, that is it is NONE. This is quite logical as validator needs to have some input value to validate it

Validator I use:

```
def skip_if_none_none_zero_positive_validator(value: int) -> None:

    if value is None:
        return None
    elif value < 1:
        raise ValidationError(
            f'{value} must be greater or equal 1'
        )
```

Question is how it to overcome this issue?
How to save None as a legit value and simultaniously validate that it would be greate or equal 1 in case values is not None?
And enforce model level validation of course.